# How to request param inside ModelSerializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I need to return some computed value using request param.
It seems that I need to get access to request param from inside ModelSerializer.
How can I do this?

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    owner = UserSerializer()
    spot = SpotSerializer()
    is_login_user_favorite = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('owner',)

    def get_is_login_user_favorite(self, validated_date):
        return True # I need change this dynamically
```

```
class PostListAPIView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('-pk')
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access it through [**`context`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#including-extra-context). Like this:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    ...
    def get_is_login_user_favorite(self, validated_date):
        request = self.context['request'] # <-- Here
        ....
        return value # I need change this dynamically
```

Basically, request is sent to Serializer through context automatically when you are using [**`Generic API Views`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/). This is also explained in the [**`methods section(at the bottom named as 'other methods')`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#methods) of documentation.